# base displayed two times in conda

Tags: anaconda

why two bases (base) (base) in my conda why two bases (base) (base) in my conda
I genuinely want to provide assistance. I feel frustrated by the recurrence of this situation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWySl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IV80.png)